# dropzone.js on complete event with parallelUploads

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I'm trying to run some code when a dropzone file uploads.  This code works well for one-at-a-time uploads:

```
Dropzone.options.filedrop = {
    init: function () {
        this.on("complete", function (file) {
             -CODE HERE-
         });
    }
}
```

But when I set dropzone to upload multiple files at once, no on complete events are being fired:

```
Dropzone.options.filedrop = {
     parallelUploads: 2,
}
```

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

completemultiple is the event u need. uploadMultiple needs to be true for this to fire as well. Different events because one accepts a single file as parameter, the other accepts an array of files.

http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Event list says it all on the webpage. You really should read the documentation, it has all the basics like this documented.